# Calling another ViewController give error - UI API called on a background thread

Tags: ios, swift, http, user-interface, url

I am new to IOS and swift. I have app with login. on login button click, i am checkong username and password using post methode. But on success result i want to go to new viewcontroller but it gives me error **UI API called on a background thread**
Button click code is given below.
Is there any asynctask onPostExecute like android in swift, then let me know.
Thanks for help.

```
@IBAction func chkbt(_ sender: Any) {

        var url = URL(string: "http://www.miappserver.co.in:8079/chs_server/rest/menuService/getLoginDetails")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "{\"one\":\"*userid*\",\"two\":\"*password*\",\"three\":\"strimg\",\"authApiKey\":\"zpfkenaojjawlwjnbsoej-fhfbs\"}"; // which is your parameters

        let idString : String = txtUserId.text!

        let passString : String = txtPassword.text!

        let newString1 = postString.replacingOccurrences(of: "*userid*", with: idString, options: .literal, range: nil)

        let newString2 = newString1.replacingOccurrences(of: "*password*", with: passString, options: .literal, range: nil)

        request.httpBody = newString2.data(using: .utf8)

        // Getting response for POST Method

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                    return // check for fundamental networking error

                }

                // Getting values from JSON Response

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

                self.parseJSON(data)

                var users = [Meal]()

                do{

                    users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Meal>.self, from: data)

                    print(users.first?.userId)

                    //print(users.first?.userPersonName)

                    if users.first?.userId != nil {

                        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dashboard") as! Dashboard

                        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                //print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
                //print(responseString)

                do {

                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary

                }catch _ {

                    print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")

                }

            }

            task.resume()

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
   self.storyBoard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dashboard") as! Dashboard 
   self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

As `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)` runs in a background thread  regardless of you surround it with `DispatchQueue.main.async {`

---

```
@IBAction func chkbt(_ sender: Any) {

        var url = URL(string: "http://www.miappserver.co.in:8079/chs_server/rest/menuService/getLoginDetails")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "{\"one\":\"*userid*\",\"two\":\"*password*\",\"three\":\"strimg\",\"authApiKey\":\"zpfkenaojjawlwjnbsoej-fhfbs\"}"; // which is your parameters

        let idString : String = txtUserId.text!

        let passString : String = txtPassword.text!

        let newString1 = postString.replacingOccurrences(of: "*userid*", with: idString, options: .literal, range: nil)

        let newString2 = newString1.replacingOccurrences(of: "*password*", with: passString, options: .literal, range: nil)

        request.httpBody = newString2.data(using: .utf8)

        // Getting response for POST Method

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

                guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                    return // check for fundamental networking error

                }

                // Getting values from JSON Response

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

                self.parseJSON(data)

                var users = [Meal]()

                do{

                    users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Meal>.self, from: data)

                    print(users.first?.userId)

                    //print(users.first?.userPersonName)

                    if users.first?.userId != nil {

                       DispatchQueue.main.async {  

                        self.storyBoard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dashboard") as! Dashboard 

                        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
                      }

                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                //print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
                //print(responseString)

                do {

                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary

                }catch _ {

                    print ("OOps not good JSON formatted response")

                }

            }

            task.resume()

    }
```